# Is boost Range library going to be part of next C++ standard?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, c++14, boost-range

I am trying to decide if I can start using Range based algorithms in the code. If it is more likely for it to be part of c++ standard, I can use it from boost in new code. Though it looks much better than iterators, it might make it difficult for others to review and contribute to the project. I didn't find in the list of papers here. http://www.meetingcpp.com/

Comment: There was a lot of work and discussion about ranges going on around the new year of 2013 when I checked. It sounded like they were figuring things out pretty well. I personally hope this gets in.

Comment: How is this question "not constructive"? Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's still a lot of discussion and work going on around ranges.

http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/01/update-from-the-ranges-study-group

It's unlikely that the existing boost ranges will be standardized in their current form. But that doesn't mean that you shouldn't go ahead and use the existing, available tools to improve your own programs.

Comment: The discussions seem to have died a bit: after a ton of messages in January, the mailinglist traffic has sharply decreased since.

Comment: There seems to be no proposal for ranges in the papers for the Bristol meeting, so I'm afraid the answer is "no"